# Is there a way for a for loop to change the type from list to str?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

How can I have a solution which is of type string and not list? I would like my output to be 12345...49 and not [1, 2, ... ,49]

```
solution1=[]

for numbers in range(1,50):
  solution1.append(numbers)

print(solution1)
```

Solution I found:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]

Can someone help me resolve this task as I can't see how to achieve this.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Append the numbers to a string

```py
solution1 = ''

for numbers in range(1,50):
  solution1 += str(numbers)

print(solution1)
```